# Content length? Length required but set?

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to send data to a web server using a post, this is what I have so far:

```
private void entity(String id, String file)
                throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
             // Add your data
            File myFile = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file);
            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(myFile), myFile.length());

            reqEntity.setContentType("text/csv");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", id));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            //httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(myFile.length()));

        }
```

When I send the post request it comes back with content-length required, but isn't that set here?

```
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(myFile), myFile.length());
```

I don't know if what I am doing is right or not, please help, thanks

---

Edit -

When I try to set the content-length myself using

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(myFile.length()));
```

it comes back with header already set.

Hence why it is commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) and add parts using `addPart` methods with `StringBody` and `InputStreamBody` (or) `FileBody`

Comment: I don't believe Android uses this?

Comment: @SmartLemon My bad. Just by looking at the class names, I thought you were using Apache HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks for answer though, in general Java that works so accept :P

Answer (score 1):

In my case using

```
reqEntity.setChunked(false);
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That sets the length of the content for the `InputStreamEntity` which is used locally when writing the data to the `OutputStream`. It doesn't set that value as a parameter for your request. You'll need to set that header yourself.

Comment: Oh, I think I see why. You're setting the entity twice. Why?

Comment: `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));` followed by `httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);`

Comment: Ahh yeah, how would I add them both then?